# How can I use FluentFile in Rhino ETL DSL?

Tags: .net, boo, rhino-etl

I have been playing around with the Rhino ETL library and really like the direction that it's going. However I have found that the bad part about it is the documentation is sparse and there doesn't seem to be enough good information on how to create these pipeline processes and especially using the DSL.

I am just attempting to create a DSL file to load a file and export the data into another file to see how this all could fit together. What I have so far is this.

```
[DelimitedRecord("\t")]
class User:
  public Name as string
  public Phone as string
  public Email as string

operation import_file:
  file = Rhino.Etl.Core.Files.FluentFile(typeof(User)).From("""E:\Fake\Book1.txt""")
  for row in file:
    yield Row.FromObject(row)

operation export_file:
  file = Rhino.Etl.Core.Files.FluentFile(typeof(User)).To("""E:\Fake\Test.txt""")
  for row in rows:
    record = User(Name: row["Name"])
    file.Write(record)

process ImportFile:
  import_file()
  export_file()
```

It throws this exception

File.boo(1,2): BCE0064: Boo.Lang.Compiler.CompilerError: No attribute with the name 'DelimitedRecord' or 'DelimitedRecordAttribute' was found (attribute names are case insensitive). Did you mean 'System.Diagnostics.DelimitedListTraceListener' ?

If I remove the attribute part I get this error

Exception: Failed to create pipeline ImportFile: The class User must be marked with the [DelimitedRecord] or [FixedLengthRecord] Attribute.
Exception: Failed to execute operation File.import_file: The class User must be marked with the [DelimitedRecord] or [FixedLengthRecord] Attribute.

Any ideas here? Or are there any examples of how to use the FluentFile within a DSL for Rhino ETL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DelimitedRecordAttribute](http://fisheye3.atlassian.com/browse/filehelpers/tags/stable/FileHelpers/Attributes/DelimitedRecordAttribute.cs?r=617) is in the [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) assembly, FileHelpers namespace.

Comment: This is true. I have made sure that the FileHelpers assembly is referenced within my project and even in the same folder as my executable. I also tried to add an "import FileHelpers" to the top of my DSL file. It will threw the same exceptions.

Comment: Well, the error says it can't find the attribute class... so it has to be some missing reference... try using SharpDevelop to write your boo code. Also see this etl sample: http://www.mail-archive.com/rhino-tools-dev@googlegroups.com/msg00343.html

Comment: I was finally able to come back and revisit this and the link you posted worked fine for what I needed to do.